# What is the best way to show partner page header on my web site?

Tags: php, embedding

I've created a website (Wordpress / PHP) which has a some services. Anyone can use this acccessing my website.

To get more trafic, I will be having partners that can use my services on "their site".

In reality, the page is still on my server but will be using the header (logo, menu etc) from my partners website. This makes it transparent for the normal user (they still think they are on my partners website).

My question is: What is the best way to copy my partners header and display it on my own site?

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do when integrating WordPress blogs into 3rd party sites is

- have them serve a `top.html` and `bottom.html` file than I can fetch (frequently using a cron job, not on every request using `include()` though)
- Serve any WordPress page so that `top.html` is on top, then comes my WordPress output, then comes `bottom.html`.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. Good answer. I've had the same thoughts as well in order not to load external content on every page request.